# How do I execute a program in gnome and make it use another gtk theme other than the default one?

Tags: gnome, gtk

I use a dark theme and the program that I am trying to run hard-codes some color values that make it unusable with the dark theme settings. I want to run this program without the dark theme being applied. Is this possible?

The application that I'm trying to retheme is the ActiveState Komodo IDE.

Comment: For GTK3 see also [Enable/set theme:variant on a per-application basis](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14129)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Launch the program as so:

`GTK2_RC_FILES=/path/to/your/theme/gtkrc application-command`

I got this from [here](http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/setting-a-custom-gtk-theme-for-specific-applications/), which has some additional information about more complicated scenarios.

Comment: tried with `GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /opt/ide/eclipse` and does't worked

Comment: This is a very old answer. You probably want something like `GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light eclipse`, but I haven't tried this.