# Launch a GTK3 aplication without customized gtk settings?

Tags: configuration, gtk

In previous versions of gtk it was easy to launch one instance of an application with default gtk settings:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES= epdfview
```

But for version 3, it won't work anymore:

```
GTK3_RC_FILES= evince
```

has no effect. Is this convenience definitely gone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok the implementation has changed and details can be found in the documentation for the [GtkCssProvider](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.3/GtkCssProvider.html) class. To use plain default settings, one can now use following:

```
GTK_DATA_PREFIX= gtk3-app
```

Comment: How do I set up a custom theme for a GTK3 app, using the above method?

Comment: @HRJ - [like this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185115)