# Run GTK2 application with different color theme

Tags: gvim, gtk2

I want to run `gvim` with a dark color theme, so that the tabs don't stand in contrast to the dark colorscheme:

[image: Adwaita]

[image: Clearlooks-Zenburn]

There appears to be a way to do this in [GTK 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14129/gtk-enable-set-dark-theme-on-a-per-application-basis).

Is there a way to do this in GTK 2 without changing the color scheme for all applications?

Answer (score 0):

A hack solution is to edit `~/.gtkrc-2.0`, wait until the application starts and edit the file again.

You can automate it.

Assuming `Adwaita` is your default theme and that you want to switch to `Clearlooks-Zenburn`, write a script called `darkgtk2start` and make it executable with `chmod +x filename`:

```
sed -i 's/gtk-theme-name="Adwaita"/gtk-theme-name="Clearlooks-Zenburn"/' ~/.gtkrc-2.0
"$@"
sleep 1
sed -i 's/gtk-theme-name="Clearlooks-Zenburn"/gtk-theme-name="Adwaita"/' ~/.gtkrc-2.0
```

Now you can start gvim dark by running:

```
./darkgtk2start gvim
```

If you move the script to a location in your `PATH` (`.local/bin/` is a common one) you don't have to use `./` any more and you can replace the `gvim` command by adding the following line to `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias gvim='darkgtk2start gvim'
```