# Except some applications (like VLC) from using the current gtk3 theme

Tags: gtk, theme, libreoffice, vlc, gtk3

I want to use a dark theme all over but to have some exceptions.

Especially VLC looks awkward with a dark theme.

Is there a way to avoid VLC using the dark theme?

Considering answers under the question [Enable/set dark theme on a per-application basis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14129/32012): not only my dark theme doesn't have variants, but the method of using `GTK_THEME=NAME_OF_THEME <application>` (or in a desktop launcher `Exec=env GTK_THEME=NAME_OF_THEME <application>`) doesn't work for VLC (or Libreoffice).

(I am in Xfce, Linux Mint 13.2).

Comment: i think you're misreading the first answer in [the question you link to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185115/222377) ... it's not running (in the `Exec=` line) `<application>` as the executable, but `env`:  `env GTK_THEME=<theme> <application> <switches>`.  using `env` sets the environment variables specified and then launches the application.

Comment: @quixotic - I know `Exec=` needs  `env` and some applications work this way, some don't (as stated in that answer: `some gtk+ 3 applications might not (yet) honor the GTK_THEME env variable`, which gives as example Nautilus). As said in my comment thereunder on what I tested as working:  synaptic, gdebi, transmission-gtk, uget-gtk, basic text editors work. Thunar and Pcmanfm do not, neither do VLC and Libreoffice. I will edit my question here too.

Comment: @quixotic - It seems the `env` variable can be replaced (and can replace) `sh -c` for the given purpose and thus works with my answer here based on this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/427440/47206.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/a/427440/47206) answer:

- create any folder `path/to/FOLDER`
- create a `/share/themes/` folder inside it (that is `path/to/FOLDER/share/themes`).
- put your app-specific GTK3 theme inside the latter
- **rename** the theme to the name of the CURRENTLY ACTIVE THEME.

Use this command to launch the application with the renamed theme instead of the currently active one:

`GTK_DATA_PREFIX=path/to/FOLDER YOUR_APPLICATON`

The path after `GTK_DATA_PREFIX=` has to be **only** to the folder that contains `/share/themes/RENAMED_THEME`, **not** to the theme itself

To have that inside a launcher, replace accordingly:

```
Exec=sh -c 'GTK_DATA_PREFIX=path/to/FOLDER YOUR_APPLICATION'
```

or

```
Exec=env GTK_DATA_PREFIX=path/to/FOLDER YOUR_APPLICATION
```

For VLC:

```
Exec=sh -c 'GTK_DATA_PREFIX=path/to/FOLDER /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U'
```

or

```
Exec=env GTK_DATA_PREFIX=path/to/FOLDER /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U
```

The change can be made in the desktop file in `/usr/share/file/applications` or in one copied in `~/.local/share/applications`.

---

Changing the system theme will reset the per-application theme, until the the folder of the latter is renamed to match the name of the former.