# GTK3 Icon theme and window decorator per-application basis

Tags: icons, gtk3, window-decorations

I found here :), I can set a particular GTK3 theme per-application basis :
[GTK - Enable/set dark theme on a per-application basis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14129/gtk-enable-set-dark-theme-on-a-per-application-basis)

Now I want to force :

- A particular icon theme per-application basis
- A particular window decorator per-application basis

The point is having a completely darked application (theme + icon special dark + window decoration)

Thanks for your help

**edit:**

For information I use cinnamon in linux mint 18.2

Further step about icon theme, i can fake it with the env variable XDG_DATA_DIRS :

- First create dir icons,
- Put your desired icon pack
- Rename icon pack as current system icon pack
- Add parent path of your freshly created icons dir into XDG_DATA_DIRS
  XDG_DATA_DIRS=/parent/of/iconsdir/:$XDG_DATA_DIRS

Answer (score 2):

**edit/** After searching and experimenting a bit, I found a way to partially do that, so i created an account here, to answer to my guest account question
**/edit**

---

For particular icon set per-application basis :

Derived from [Except some applications (like VLC) from using the current gtk3 theme](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407302/except-some-applications-like-vlc-from-using-the-current-gtk3-theme/407316#407316)

- create any folder `path/to/FOLDER`
- create a `icons/` folder inside it
- put your desired icon set folder in it and rename that folder with the name of current icon set

After that you can force the use of this icon set with :

`XDG_DATA_DIRS=/path/to/FOLDER/:$XDG_DATA_DIRS <application>`

For dark theme you can use [breeze-dark](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1002340/) icon set

---

Cinnamon use metacity border-decoration, this is in `themes/metacity-1/` folder. 
I don't know how to customize it for a specific application. The `XDG_DATA_DIRS` hack above won't work.

---

So if you want custom theme and icons, you can write in a terminal :

`GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark XDG_DATA_DIRS=/path/to/FOLDER/:$XDG_DATA_DIRS <application>`

And for launching app with these settings in application .desktop file :

`Exec=sh -c "GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark XDG_DATA_DIRS=/path/to/FOLDER/:$XDG_DATA_DIRS <application> %F"`

Comment: An ugly way of doing it and not really a single override.

Comment: Yes I know, please show me the beautiful way to do this ;)

Comment: @brouillon Awesome, working for me under i3. Thank you very much!

Comment: @brouillon Thank you! I managed to run my Gtk app on Mac with my favorite theme. You are absolutely awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple way of doing this. take the icon theme that has the most icons that you would use in your final set of icons. copy it and name it as you like (eg:- `my-icons`). after that change the name property in the file `index.theme` to your icon theme name. and then find the icons that you would want to change. I recommend finding SVG versions of icons because it can be used in every resolution since it is scalable.
then put the x.svg file inside `app/scalable` directory inside your icon theme. or if you have a png file put it in the closest resolution (eg:- if you have a 38x38 icon 36x36 folder). if you can't find a folder to put it in create a folder because I think the location doesn't that matter that much you can put you files anywhere as long as it is inside the your icon folder. now, follow the below steps to help the system find correct icon for the correct app.

1. find the specific `.desktop` file for a application in `/usr/share/applications`
2. then, copy the value of the `Icon=` property and set it as the name for the icon name or copy the icon name (just the name, not path nor extention) and set it as the value for the `Icon` property (need sudo privileges). example icon name, icon-file: `Viber.png` icon-name: `Viber`.

after that, put the icon folder inside `~/.local/share/icons` or `~/.icons` (recommend the first one). finally, use system settings to set the icon theme if you use something like `gnome` or `kde` or else follow the below steps.

open `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and add the line `gtk-icon-theme-name=my-icons`. if that property already exists change the name of the icon theme according to your theme name.

**Extra tips:**

1. if you have trouble finding the exact file to use in your own icon theme, cd to the location of that specific icon theme and use a utility like `fzf` to find the files
2. change `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file if you want gtk2 support.
3. if you have trouble finding SVG icons goto a website like [icons8](https://icons8.com) to find them. but there's a danger, after visiting that you might not use your own icons.
4. sometimes the files will be in `scalable/apps` but as I said, directory doesn't matter if we forget about organizing.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked, OP wants to have an application *use* a different icon theme, as well as a window decoration theme.