# GTK3 - How to set Font on a per-application basis?

Tags: gnome, gtk3

I have seen this question about [setting a GTK3 theme on a per-application basis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14129/504663). However that question is about changing the theme but no mentions about the font/font size.

Is it possible to change the font of a **specific** GTK3 application?

P.S: I know how to change the font using gnome-tweaks tool but that affect all GTK applications.