# How do I execute a program in Xfce and make it use another xfwm4 theme other than the default one?

Tags: bash, python, xfce, window-manager, window-decorations

I want to run a python script (the one in the answer to [Python - how to make transparent window with gtk.Window but not with Gtk.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577367/python-how-to-make-transparent-window-with-gtk-window-but-not-with-gtk-window)) that displays a transparent window. I'm running it from a bash script in Xfce, and the purpose of displaying the transparent window is to be able to easily define an area on the screen. So, it's important to be able to easily resize this transparent window. Modern themes are difficult to resize. I know about [How do I execute a program in gnome and make it use another gtk theme other than the default one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/how-do-i-execute-a-program-in-gnome-and-make-it-use-another-gtk-theme-other-than) which inspired the wording of my title here.

However, changing the GTK theme has no effect on the ease of resizing windows. In fact, it leaves the transparent window unchanged. In Xfce settings, the themes I want to use are in the Window Manager, unlike the GTK themes, which are in the Appearance application. Also, while the GTK themes are configured with gtkrc files, xfwm4 themes are configured with themerc files.

I want to use a theme like Retro or even RedmondXP for their ease of grabbing the frame with the mouse for resizing.

Actually, it would be even better if somebody could tell me how to control the window frame from within the python script in a way that would work on any desktop, not just Xfce. I don't care if the frame is pretty. I just want it to be easy to resize.

Or, even if my main purpose could be addressed - defining an area on the screen - that would also answer my question. Is there an easy way from bash or python to let someone draw a rectangle on the screen and then resize it?